# How can an Entity validate a foreign key?

Tags: .net, architecture, foreign-keys, entity, data-access-layer

In my data access layer, I have the Entities assembly and Repository assembly.
In the Entities assembly, I have Address class

```
public class Address
{
  public int AddressId {get; set;}
  public string StreetAddress {get; set;}
  public string City {get; set;}
  public int StateId {get; set;} // foreign key to State table
  public int CountryCode {get; set;} // foreign key to Country table

  public bool Validate()
  {
    // I can verify the StreetAddress and City for empty string and maxlength here
    // but how can I verify the StateId and CountryCode here?
  }
}
```

In the Repository assembly, which references the Entities assembly, I have Address Repository. I'm not using Entity framework, but using Dapper for DB operations.

```
public class AddressRepository : IAddressRepository
{
  public int Create(Address address)
  {
    if (address == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(address));
    if (address.Validate())
    {
      // ... create address here ...
    }
  }
}
```

as in the above code, my Address entity cannot call any repository method such as StateRepository.Get(int stateId) to validate StateId (or CountryRepository for CountryCode) because that would become a circular reference. Of course, SQL Server will throw FK constraint exception if StateId and CountryCode or not valid entries in the respective tables, but would like to avoid that if possible. What am I doing wrong in this architecture? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is your environment a DI one?
If so, you can implement the IValidatableObject and then use the method GetService of the ValidationContext object.

Look at this link for understand better what I mean:
[Validation](https://andrewlock.net/injecting-services-into-validationattributes-in-asp-net-core/)